# Letting VSCode Intellisense suggest "if block" instead of "if" by default

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellisense

When I make a if block, I type "if" and then the Intellisense shows **if** first

[image]

But in 99% cases I need **if block**. How do I let him suggest the block for the first choice with which I can save one second each time I input the block?

Comment: Look this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // Controls whether snippets are shown with other suggestions and how
>   they are sorted.
>
> //  - top: Show snippet suggestions on top of other suggestions.
>   //  - bottom: Show snippet suggestions below other suggestions.
>   // 
>   - inline: Show snippets suggestions with other suggestions.
>   //  - none: Do not show snippet suggestions.

```
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
```

`"inline"` is the default, change it to .  Now the `if` block snippet will be the top choice.